# Problem with Chapterbib and Matlab-prettifier

Tags: code, matlab, matlab-prettifier, chapterbib

I am trying to insert a Maltab code in a Latex document using Matlab-Prettifier. I am configuring the package as indicated below:

```
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstset{
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle         =\ttfamily\scriptsize,
  escapechar         = ",
  literate           = {~} {$\smallsim$}{1},
  mlshowsectionrules = true,
}
```

However, after Latex compilation, in the first use of the line-continuation (...) in the Matlab code, it appears characters that are not in the original code, as indicated in the figure below by 'b@x':

[image]

No warning is generated after compilation.

When I remove the Chapterbib package, this does not occur anymore. Chapterbib is being used without any special configuration.

Does anyone know what I can do to correct such a problem?

Here, I include a basic Latex document that produces the same problem I described above:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{chapterbib} 

\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstset{
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle         =\ttfamily\scriptsize,
  escapechar         = ",
  mlshowsectionrules = true,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in listings, revealed in specific circumstances, but I don't know enough to make the MWE without matlab-prettifier, and the three dots (which are special syntax for matlab). The problem is that listings (in `\lst@CalcLostSpaceAndOutput`) outputs the contents of the scratch box `\@tempboxa`, perhaps without having set it anywhere, or set it only in a local group.

Demonstration

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{
  style = Matlab-editor,
}

\makeatletter \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{oops!}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

As a work-around insert

```
\makeatletter \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{}\makeatother
```

in the document, at least at the beginning, but potentially in more places.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I inserted "\makeatletter \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{}\makeatother" in the document and the problem was solved!

Comment: Hurrah. Had exactly the same issue. This does indeed fix it. Placed the workaround command at the start of my appendix where I've got the code located.

Comment: By the way, chapterbib has been updated to not leave anything in `\@tempboxa`.